# How to have different fake functions called for multiple calls on a Jasmine spy

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

Say I'm spying on a method like this:

```
spyOn(util, "foo").andCallFake(function() {
    //some code
});
```

The function under test calls util.foo multiple times.

Is it possible to have the spy to call different fake functions for each next  call?

The question is similar to this one: [How to have different return values for multiple calls on a Jasmine spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898613/how-to-have-different-return-values-for-multiple-calls-on-a-jasmine-spy) but I need to call a function instead of returning  values.
If there is no native way to do  so,  how do I "reset" the  spy to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to route your spy to actually callThrough the second/subsequent times after it has been used to fake a method earlier.

I feel this illustrates what you've been trying to achieve. [Fiddle to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/20/)

```
var util = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log("Foo has been called")
  }
}

someFunction = function() {
  console.log("lets call utils foo");
  util.foo();
  console.log("lets call utils foo one more time");
  util.foo();
  console.log("lets call utils foo one last time");
  util.foo();
}

describe("spec to util's foo multiple times", function() {
  it('test', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.resetSpy = function() {
      self.spyVar.and.callThrough();
    };
    self.spyVar = spyOn(util, 'foo').and.callFake(function(e) {
      console.log("Foo hasn't been called, instead a Fake method has been called")
      self.resetSpy();
    });
    someFunction();
    expect(util.foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Notes:**

- `someFunction` is a function that calls `util.foo` three times.
- Say you'd want to fake it once but the next two calls you want to
  actually call the function itself, then we can initially set the spy
  to use a fake method however for the second and third calls, we reset
  teh spy to actually `callThrough`
- `self.resetSpy` is an internal function on the spec that I invoke after the first spy call.
- more info on reset the spy is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885591/how-do-we-clear-spy-programmatically-in-jasmine)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap an anonymous function around it:

```
var count=0;
event.on(function(){
count++;
if(count==1){
//at first
firstfunc();
}else{
//the rest
secondfunc();
}
});
```

Comment: Could you please  fit it to spies and fake  calls as i do not understand how to adapt your answer?

Comment: Simply replace event.on with spyOn().andCallFake(