# Detect synthetic click in React during testing with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, html-input

I am building an app with React. I am hiding a file input element (`<input type="file"/>`) "behind" a react-bootstrap `Button` to be able to control styling. So, when the button is clicked I turn around and fire a synthetic click event on the text input element, as shown below.

```
class OpenFileButton extends React.Component {
  ...
  clickHandler() {
    this.refs['input'].click();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonGroup>
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={this.props.someCallback}
            ref="input" style={{display: 'none'}}/>
          <Button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Open File</Button>
        </div>
      </ButtonGroup>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to be able to test this with Jest/Enzyme. However, while I can simulate a click event on the button, I haven't figured out how to detect a synthetic click event on the file input element.

I have tried using Jest/Enzyme to mock the click method on the input element.

```
const component = mount(<OpenFileButton/>);
const fileInput = component.find('input');
const button    = component.find('Button');
fileInput.click = jest.fn();
button.simulate('click');
expect(fileInput.click).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

However, mocking the `click` method this way does not work. I also can't add an `onClick` attribute, i.e. `fileInput.props().onClick = jest.fn()` does not work.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27442497/5218951) is about detecting synthetic click events in the code itself, not in the test code, and so is not relevant.

So, how can I detect a (synthetic) click event on a DOM element using Jest/Enzyme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here involves spying on the `click` method of the particular file input element that I'm interested in. I can thus check to see if this file-input-element-click-spy was called after a click is simulated on the button element, as follows:

```
const openFileButtonWrapper = mount(<OpenFileButton/>);
const buttonWrapper = openFileButtonWrapper.find(Button);
const fileInputWrapper = openFileButtonWrapper.find('input [type="file"]');
const fileInput = fileInputWrapper.get(0);
const clickInputSpy = spyOn(fileInput, 'click');
buttonWrapper.simulate('click');
expect(clickInputSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

*The answer by @AbdennourTOUMI used Sinon's `spy` method which reminded me that Jest uses some Jasmine functionality, including its `spyOn` method, that isn't obvious from the Jest documentation. So, even though that other answer ended up spying on _all_ input elements, which is not ideal, it did send me in the right direction, so thank you, Adbennour.*

Answer (score 3):

`<input />` or `this.refs.input` is an instance of `HTMLInputElement`.

Then you can test if `HTMLInputElement.prototype.click` is called .

Using [sinon](/questions/tagged/sinon) you will have :

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';

const clickInputSpy = sinon.spy(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'click')
const component = mount(<OpenFileButton/>);

const button    = component.find('Button');

button.simulate('click');
expect(clickInputSpy.called).toBeTruthy();
clickInputSpy.restore();
```

```js
const clickInputSpy = sinon.spy(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'click');


console.log(
 'Is <input /> clicked ? ', clickInputSpy.called 
);
document.querySelector('input').click();


console.log(
 'Is <input /> clicked ? ', clickInputSpy.called 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/1.15.4/sinon.min.js"></script>

<input />
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you. Works perfectly. Just to directly answer my question, in order to do the same with Jasmine/Jest instead of Sinon, do the following: (A) Replace your `sinon.spy(...` with `spyOn(...`. (B) Change the `expect` statement to `expect(clickInputSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()` (or something similar). (C) If you need to restore the spy within the same `it` or `describe` block within which the spy was defined, use `clickInputSpy.and.callThrough()` as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23723064/5218951).

Comment: However, there is a problem, though not necessarily completely insurmountable. The spy spies on _any/all_ input element(s), not the specific one that I am interested in. In many cases there probably won't be multiple different `input` elements that need to be differentiated, so that might be OK. However, it _does_ make the test somewhat non-optimal. It also makes this strategy completely unworkable if you ever want to "transfer" a click between two elements of the same type, e.g. clicking on one button which then programmatically clicks another button.

Comment: So I don't know if it is possible to spy on the instance directly . If so, use `spy(component.ref('input'), 'click')` instead of `spy(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'click')`. ..It might work or  `spy(component.find('input').get(0), 'click')`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I had already used your last suggestion, i.e. `spy(...find...get..., 'click')`, in the alternative answer that I posted and it seems to be working. In any case, thanks again for originally sending me off in the right direction with your initial answer.